# Restore column from PostgreSQL dump

Tags: postgresql, backup

Is it possible to restore the particular column from the PostgreSQL dump? I know that it is possible to specify the table to restore, but what about column from this table?

Comment: Import the table using a different table name, or in a different schema, and update the old table from it.

Comment: @wildplasser thank you! This is what I've done actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @wildpasser mentioned in comments, the best way to do this is following:

1. Import required table using different table name (particular table could be imported using `psql COPY 'different_table_name' FROM 'file_name'`
2. Update the desired columns of your table from the `different_table_name`
3. Drop `different_table_name`